# How can I upload my whole iPhoto-Library to flickr?

Tags: photos.app, flickr

Is there any plugin or other tool that I can use to upload my whole iPhoto Library to flickr? What do I need to do with that tool?

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this natively with iPhoto, although [FlickrExport by Connected Flow](http://connectedflow.com/flickrexport/) does offer some additional features. If you go to `Preferences` - `Accounts` you can add your Flickr account and it will allow you to share your photos and albums natively.

[image: iPhoto Accounts]

Comment: or you can do it that way! ; )

Comment: Can these tools alos sync automatically (as a means of backup). I mean that newly added pictures are automatically uploaded to flickr?

Comment: @daefu As far as I am aware no. There is no plugin I know off or have found that will do an automatic sync or backup. You have to innate the sharing. I did a thorough search for similar Flickr plugins before and have yet to find one.

Answer (score 4):

You can use plugins like [Connected Flow](http://connectedflow.com/flickrexport/) its quite cheap at £12.

Once installed it adds the ability to share images with a flickr account.

This works in the same was as the iPhoto Facebook uploader, you select all the images, at the bottom right where you find the share button (for Facebook, email, etc.) you will also see a Flickr option, use this.

Answer (score 4):

The "sharing" feature in iPhoto is not designed to upload your whole library to Flickr. Neither is Connected Flow. They work with a subset of selected photos. I came up empty handed in my own search for a tool that would upload and synchronize my iPhoto Library with Flickr. I ended up programming my own tool. I successfully used it to upload my whole iPhoto library to flickr, which took about 3 days for 36,000 photos, including metadata synchronization. Unfortunately, it is not reliable enough to share (sorry for the tease). Flickr has a great API (Application Programming Interface), which is how my program communicates with Flickr. Flickr's App Garden is where applications which use the Flickr API are registered, and also a good place to discover new and existing applications. http://www.flickr.com/services/

Note that a program that uploads an entire iPhoto library to Flickr would not necessarily need to be a plug-in. It could be a stand alone application. Internally, iPhoto uses an [sql database](http://tumblr.maccodemonkey.com/post/9111450792/more-on-iphotomain-db-iphotoaux-db-date-formats) to store data. It is rather accessible for programming purposes. An application that interfaces with this database and the Flickr API could do what you want.

I recommend monitoring Flickr's App Garden for new applications and hope that one that does what you want appears soon.

Comment: This is a great recommendation. I would only add, that the incremental upload is a nice way to start. Upload 20 or so pictures in 4 albums using a few tools to get a feel for how the metadata uploads. Once you're convinced it's good and want to go Pro or not on Flickr - you can then schedule the uploads by the thousands and make good progress to getting your entire collection uploaded in a manageable fashion.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question but since I have found a pretty cool solution and none of the listed here, by today, have been useful for me, I just wanted to share it here with you guys.

I'm using this python script: https://github.com/elek/puploadr

Just use your iPhoto Library Masters subfolder (it should be at: `~/Pictures/iPhoto Library/Masters/`) as parameter and use it.

If something goes wrong just re-run the command and it will skip already uploaded pics and/or videos.

Answer (score 1):

this works like a charm! 
https://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/backup-to-flickr-for-iphoto/id733300407?mt=12
Full backup of your iphoto or aperture library. all structure is kept

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize what the app does and why you recommend it.